# How to run a single testng test case in multiple parallel threads

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I want to run single test NG test case in any browser multiple times and parallely

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: For running the same test case multiple times, you can use this code @Test(invocationCount = 100)

public void testCount() {

}

Comment: And for parallel execution you can use multi threading.

Answer (score 2):

A.1. To run a test case multiple times use invocationCount attribute in @Test annotation. This invocationCount determines how many times TestNG should run this test method.

```
@Test(invocationCount = ?)
```

A.2. To run a test case mutiple times in different threads use threadPoolSize attribute in @Test annotation. This attribute tells TestNG to create a thread pool to run the test method via multiple threads

```
@Test(invocationCount = ?, threadPoolSize = ?)
```

B.3. To run a test case in multiple browsers in different threads initialize your webDriver as ThreadLocal

```
private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
```

In testng.xml create tests with browser name as a parameter

```
<test name="Test">
    <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"></parameter>
    <classes>
        <class name="MyTestCases" />
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Test">
    <parameter name="browserName" value="Chrome"></parameter>
    <classes>
        <class name="MyTestCases" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

use @Parameters() to fetch the value of browser name

```
@BeforeTest
@Parameters("browserName")
public void webDriverHandler(String browserName){
  // String browserName contains parameter value
}
```

Create a Driver handler and a testbase classes. Use Driver handler to set and get webDriver and use your base class to fetch the browser name

Driver handler:

```
public class DriverHandler {

private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    return webDriver.get();
}

public static void setWebDriver(String browser) {

     WebDriver driver = null;

     if (browser.contains("firefox")) {

       driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    } else if (browser.contains("chrome")) {

       ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
       driver = new ChromeDriver(options);  

    }
    webDriver.set(driver);
}


}
```

testbase:

```
public class TestBase { 

 @BeforeTest
 @Parameters("browserName")
 public void threadHandler(String browserName) {

    Thread.currentThread().setName(browser.toLowerCase());
    if (DriverManager.getDriver() == null)
        DriverManager.setWebDriver(browser);
 }


}
```